# GORM delete operation : Found two representations of same collection

Tags: hibernate, grails, collections, grails-orm

```
@Entity
public class Contact{
    List associations

    static hasMany[
    associations:Contact
    ]

    static mapping[
    associations cascade:"all-delete-orphan"
    ]
}
```

and i have service for deleting associations from `Contact` entity like this

```
Contact.withTransaction{status ->
        user.contacts.collect{Contact c->
            c.associations.collect{Contact association->
                c.associations.remove(association)
            }
        }
     }
```

when trying this i get `org.hibernate.HibernateException:Found two representations of same collection: Contact.associations`

do i making a mistake or any other way to delete associations from Contact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you should not use collect in this case. i think the appropriate method would be each. you don't need to use a withTransaction at this point, expecting you would use a new hibernate session. try this:

```
def assocs = []
// store collection to avoid concurrent modification exception by during delection with in each   method
assocs += user.contacts.associations
assocs.each {
   // because of your cascase setting all orphans will be deleted automatically
   user.contacts.removeFromAssociations(it)
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer.but i get "org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: no signature of method org.hibernate.collection.PersistentList.removeFromAssociations() is applicable for arguments" .... when i try it

Comment: hmm, have tried within the each method user.contacts.associations.remove(it) instead of removeFromAssociations(it)?

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a shorter way to do the task:

```
def contact = Contact.get(...) // retrieve a contact
contact.associations.clear() // remove all associations of the contact
```

If you are not familiar with GORM, it's better to start with [this blog post](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/07/02/gorm-gotchas-part-2/).

Comment: its ok for just one contact. but i want to delete all associations of all contacts in that case im getting exceptions :S

Comment: @Sedat: you can loop through the contacts with a for loop(http://groovy.codehaus.org/Looping)... oh wait, you want to delete all the contact of a user? I don't know which kind of relations between user & contact, but if it is a hasMany - belongsTo one, why don't you try user.contacts.clear() ?

Comment: i want to delete associations of the contacts :S

Comment: @Sedat: which contact? all of them?

Comment: associations of all contacts but its ok i found it. When i was trying to delete associations i also trying to delete some contacts because associations are also contact so when i trying to delete them it throws exceptions. so now i get the contacts which i want with a sql query then i delete all. Thanks all for interest.

Comment: @Sedat: good work. You may want to create an answer for this question.:)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Problem was because of deleting the associations that in array. When i getting contact list it also give me associations because associations are also instance of contact. So firstly, i get the contact list with sql query by getting only contacts then i deleted the associations of contacts. Much Thanks to everyone especially to  Hoàng Long :)